# How can i create a persistent Docker volume?

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to create a persistent volume for postgresql so that when i do 'docker-compose.yml down' i don't lose the database. Currently i have a volume for postgresql but it's empty and the data is not going in it, can anyone help ?

```
volumes:
  dependency-track:
  postgresql:

services:

  postgresql10:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dtrack
      - POSTGRES_USER=dtrack
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    restart: unless-stopped

  dtrack-apiserver:
    image: dependencytrack/apiserver
    depends_on:
      - postgresql10


etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs an extra data at the end of the service volume path.

```
volumes:
  dependency-track:
  postgresql:

services:

  postgresql10:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dtrack
      - POSTGRES_USER=dtrack
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a volume for a postgres container, inside of a docker-compose file, with something like:

```
dbpostgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - /your/path/here:/var/lib/postgresql
```

Comment: You mean like this - /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/postgressql:/var/lib/postgresql ?

Comment: I still cant get it to work, when i run docker-compose up -d the volume is created and the dir has a _data directory then a data directory inside that with no files in it :(

Comment: It's ok i got it working, for the service volume it needed -postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data, the data was missing from the end.